# How to run the gcloud dispatcher with modules using dart-pub-serve?

Tags: dart, gcloud

I have multiple (dart) modules that I am running in my gcloud. During development, I'd like them to connect to my local `pub serve` servers. When I run them separately, I normally use this command:

```bash
gcloud preview app run app.yaml --dart-pub-serve 10.6.6.6:7779
```

How could I do the same with multiple modules and using one dispatcher? The dispatcher line looks like this:

```bash
gcloud preview app run dispatch.yaml \
                       ../api/app.yaml \
                       ../dashboard/app.yaml \
                       ../webserver/app.yaml
```

Providing multiple `--dart-pub-serve` arguments did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should be able to do is to set the environment variable `DART_PUB_SERVE` for each application in `app.yaml` like this:

```
env_variables:
  DART_PUB_SERVE:  'http://10.6.6.6:7779'
```

and then set it differently for each module. Leaving this environment variable for deployment is OK, as when running in production the output from `pub build` is always used.

Take a look at https://www.dartlang.org/cloud/client-server/.

The option `--dart-pub-serve` is deprecated.

Also you should change to using `runtime: custom` and manually run `pub build` for each module before deploying.